# Count values under value in a Google Sheets column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, vba

I am trying to create a formula in a spreadsheet which has several thousand lines. I am struggling with the part where I need to find out how many children (*y*) does parent (*x*) have - counting value until value changes.
I've tried using  `=IF(A2=OFFSET(A2,-1,0),OFFSET(B2,-1,0)+1,1)` which currently gives count to child products.
The ultimate goal would be to output values of all children based on the count.

```
    +---+------+-------+-------+--------------+--+
    | 1 | Type | Count | Value | Child Values |  |
    +---+------+-------+-------+--------------+--+
    | 2 | x    |     1 | A     | B            |  |
    | 3 | y    |       | B     |              |  |
    | 4 | x    |     2 | C     | D,E          |  |
    | 5 | y    |       | D     |              |  |
    | 6 | y    |       | E     |              |  |
    | 7 | x    |     1 | F     | G            |  |
    | 8 | y    |       | G     |              |  |
    +---+------+-------+-------+--------------+--+
```

So if *x* has 2 children, then the formula would output values of next 2 cells next to it (Child Values). The parents can have up to 8 children and would need to take a number of next cell values based on count.
Is this second part even possible without Excel VBA? I appreciate your help!

Comment: How does x have two children in the above? It is linked to A,C,F as well as B,D,E,G. Do you mean the max number of child values in a row for x (D,E) ?

Comment: x's were actually unique, I didn't bring out other columns in which they differ, x is just what defines that it's parent of children under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best answer, but it does avoid VBA.  You do have to have a dummy *x* with no children at the bottom of the list.

Your count formula is:

```
=IF(A2="y","",MATCH("x",INDEX($A:$A,ROW()+1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)),0)-1)
```

- `INDEX($A:$A,ROW()+1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A)` will set a reference from the next row down to the end of the list providing there is a value in every cell in column `A` from `A1` to the end of list.
- `MATCH("x",....,0)` will return the row number *in the referenced range* that the next *x* occurs on. Minus one from this will give the number of children for the *x*.
- `IF(A2="y","",.......)` makes sure the count only appears on the *x* rows.

As you'll only have a maximum of 8 children you could use this formula to return the Child Values.

```
=IF(B2="","",CONCATENATE(IF(B2>=1,C3,""),IF(B2>=2," ," & C4,""),IF(B2>=3," ," & C5,""),IF(B2>=4," ," & C6,""),IF(B2>=5," ," & C7,""),IF(B2>=6," ," & C8,""),IF(B2>=7," ," & C9,""),IF(B2>=8," ," & C10,"")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem in question, I was able to modify it according to my additional needs and resolve my issue.